# AngularJS - Attach a directive to every anchor found

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm building an Ionic app where content is returned via `$sce.trustAsHtml(data.content);` I'd like to programmatically search through the returned HTML and bind an `ng-click="openInWebView(url)` where the url param is the copied value of whatever value was in the initial anchor tags a-href attribute.

For example if the content of the html is:

```
<p>lorem ipsum</p>
<a href="http://some-story.com/article">A Story!</a>
```

Keep in mind this needs to be done for each `<a>` element in the content because an article will often contain a number of different links.

View HTML:

`<div ng-bind-html="articleHtml" class="article__content" follow-anchor></div>`

Directive:

```
hack.directive('followAnchor', ['$followAnchor', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        // terminal: true,
        priority: 1001,
        link: function($scope, $element, attrs) {
            anchor = $element.find('a').clone();
            anchor.attr('ng-click', 'openInWebView()');
            anchor = $compile(anchor)($scope);
            $element.find('a').replaceWith(anchor);
        }
    };
}]);
```

Controller:

```
   $scope.openInWebView = function(url) {
        var browsingOptions = {
            location: 'no',
            clearcache: 'yes',
            toolbar: 'yes',
            mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction: 'yes',
            shouldPauseOnSuspend: 'yes',
            closebuttoncaption: 'Close'
        };

        document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
            $cordovaInAppBrowser.open(url, '_blank', browsingOptions)
            .then(function(event) {
                console.log('success!');
            }).catch(function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        }, false);
    };
```

I'm sure that my directive is incorrect, but I'm stuck as to how I should proceed or if this is even the correct way of doing something like this.

Comment: Instead of adding a directive, do it directly `anchor.bind('click', ...)`